# Gatsby Transitions with AniLink - not working

Tags: gatsby

Just trying out AniLink but it seems that the package has some issues working. Testing out the link doesnt seem to work and it seems that the import is throwing an error as well:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'gatsby-plugin-transition-link/AniLink'. '/Users/robert/Software/bDev/evu/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-transition-link/AniLink/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/gatsby-plugin-transition-link` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'gatsby-plugin-transition-link/AniLink';`ts(7016)
```

The component is a banner.js file being used within the layout component.

I import AniLink:

```
import AniLink from 'gatsby-plugin-transition-link/AniLink';
```

and the try using it but nothing happens:

```
<AniLink fade to="allProducts">View Now</AniLink> // or to="/allProducts"
```

my config file:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `EssentialVu`,
    description: `Some really sweet ecommerce site.`,
    author: `@gatsbyjs`,
  },

  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-stripe`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-stripe`,
      options: {
        objects: ["Sku"],
        secretKey: process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY,
        downloadFiles: true,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-transition-link",
      options: {
          layout: require.resolve(`./src/components/layout.js`)
        },
    }
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/gatsby-icon.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
    // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.dev/offline
    // `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
  ],

}
```

I also have gsap installed : `"gsap": "^2.1.3",`

Answer (score 0):

its a basic typescript error that includes typechecking.. create a `{filename}.dt.s` file if you dont have already and add this piece of code below:

```
declare module "gatsby-plugin-transition-link/AniLink";
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try?

```
npm install @types/gatsby-plugin-transition-link
```

Comment: I'm facing this issue too, and this doesn't seem to fix it. Returns a E404 error.